# unable to edit QlineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I was using an example out of a book called "c++ programming a gui with qt 4 second edition", and ran into the following problem; I can't edit QlineEdit. I am pretty sure it is the QRegExp that is causing the problem because when  i commented it out I was suddenly able to enter input into the QlineEdit dialog.

here is the following code:

cells.h:

```
    #ifndef CELLS
    #define CELLS

    #include <QDialog>
    #include "ui_cells.h"

    class cells: public QDialog, public Ui::cells
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        cells(QWidget *parent = 0);

    private slots:
        void on_lineEdit_textChanged();
    };


    #endif // CELLS
```

cells.cpp:

```
    #include <QtWidgets>
    #include "cells.h"

    cells::cells(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
    {
        setupUi(this);

        QRegExp regExp("[A-Za-a] [1-9] [0-9] {0-2}");
        lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regExp, this));

        connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
        connect(Cancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));
    }

    void cells::on_lineEdit_textChanged()
    {
        okButton->setEnabled(lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
    }
```

and finally main.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    #include "cells.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        cells *dialog = new cells;
        dialog->show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, figured out the problem:

on the declaration of regExp it should be:

```
    QRegExp regExp = ("[A-Za-z] [1-9] [0-9] {0,2}")
```

There was supposed to be a comma at {0,2} not a hyphen (-)